# Using Telegram on Raspberry Pi to receive and print a message to defult usb printer

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

I have a RPi3 set up with a printer and Telegram bot.
I want to be able to listen to incoming messages and then print them to the default printer (with text and images).

I don't need a complete solution but could someone point me to the direction on how to start this project? Where should I look?

I saw the commands on the botAPI for receiving messages, but how to I send them to the printer?

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Use [subprocess](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/) module

Comment: could you please elaborate on that? Thanks.